# Unable to debug a C# Windows Forms control Library in VS 2010. But i can debug VB Windows Forms control Library. What is the key?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, forms

I built a C# Windows Forms control library and want to debug it. SO i placed a button on the same control and test some functionality on button click. So i placed a breakpoint in click event. But the break point does not work. But i'm sure the code in the click event is getting executed.

This is happening only in VS 2010 and only with C# but not with VB. The breakpoint is working if the language is in VB. Also i tested the same scenerio with VS 2008 and breakpoint works for both C# and VB.

So what's the mystery with VS2010 C# ???

Comment: Do you have the Async CTP installed?

Comment: create a new project of the same type and try again. What happens? When you're running in debug mode is the break point hollow or solid? If hollow you are running on compiled code different from the source. Clean and rebuild and try again.

Comment: No... i dont have Async CTP insatalled? DO i need to?

Comment: Please Give more detail for that. I am also using VS2010. If you willing Share your code, then its easiest to find whats going on. Yours, Sagotharan.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Options and check 'Debugging' options for both VS 2008 and VS2010. Ideally this should not happen unless you changed the options here.